# Use a particular id_rsa key file per host

Tags: unix, ssh, ssh-keys

I hope this is the right place to post this.

I have a VM I usually connect from work. To connect from home I was given the following instructions:

Copy and paste `./ssh/id_rsa` and `./ssh/id_rsa.pub` from the work machine to the home machine. Also make a config file like:

```
# Debian VM
Host nacho4d.dev.acme.com
# IdentityFile ~/.ssh_acme/id_rsa
 User nacho4d
 ProxyCommand ssh ns.dev.acme.com -l nacho4d nc -w 1 %h %p
# Tunnel/springboard server 
Host ns.dev.acme.com
# IdentityFile ~/.ssh_acme/id_rsa
 User nacho4d
 ProxyCommand ssh ts6.in.acme.com -l nacho4d nc -w 1 %h %p
```

So everything works good with:

```
$ ssh nacho4d.dev.acme.com
```

The problem is that I already have my own (non-work) private keys and I don't want to replace it with the work .ssh folder every time I need to use ssh. Too tedious.

How can I use a particular key, etc to connect to a specific server only?

I tried putting my files like:

- `~/.ssh/id_rsa` → home private key
- `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` → home public key
- `~/.ssh/config` → config file like above but with IdentityFile enabled
- `~/.ssh_acme/id_rsa` → work private key
- `~/.ssh_acme/id_rsa.pub` → work public key

I thought that having a config file with IndentityFile should make ssh to use a particular key ( in this case pointing to `~/.ssh_acme/id_rsa`) for that particular host, but I always get **"Permission Denied" Connection closed by remote host**.

Am I missing something? Perhaps do I need to supply the public key somewhere else too?

I checked ~./ssh/authorized_keys file in the VM and I have a ssh-rsa entry for the work-computer not the home computer (which Is I believe normal since I am using the keys provided by work.)

How come `IdentityFile ~/.ssh_acme/id_rsa` is not working as expected?
Do I really need to interchange my home/work keys everytime I need to connect to somewhere?
I am almost a beginner in ssh things, but something tells me there must be a clever way of doing this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify which key works with which host, just rename the keys and add a `IdentityFile` line for each key:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_dev_acme
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_in_acme
```

It's possible the keys in `~/.ssh_acme/id_rsa` aren't being used because the permissions aren't correct on `~/.ssh_acme` (0700) or `~/.ssh_acme/id_rsa` (0600)

Finally, this question might be more relevant on http://unix.stackexchange.com